# Does vagrant create a temp directory and files when packaging boxes

Tags: windows, vagrant

My vagrant box fail to finish being packaged due to not having enough space on disk, I'm wondering if there is any way to make sure that there are no temporary files left behind during the packaging process due to it being not finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows it's stored under `C:/Users/user.name/AppData/Local/Temp/` in folder named following this scheme `vagrant-YYYYMMDD-TSTAMP-id/`.

In other linux-like OSes it would be in `~/.vagrant.d/tmp`.

Answer (score 2):

I think all of the temp files are in `~/.vagrant.d/tmp`. Each time I have interrupted packaging, Vagrant has cleaned up automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful.